# Which sniper scope has the highest zoom and where is it found?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

In Ghost Recon Wildlands, the snipers come poorly equipped with scopes that hardly zoom in.  So far, the best scope I've found has a 6x zoom. I'd really like to get into sniping in this game, but even a 6x times zoom is weak in my opinion.  Is there anything higher? And where is it found?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So far the T5Xi Tactical Scope is the best and highest zoom in the game. 6 times normal weapon zoom.

It's located in the Koani Province. Up by the Huertas Mine.

[image]

Fastest way to get there is the helicopter. 
The mine itself shouldn't have any enemies to encounter, although there are the routine UNIDAD helicopter patrols.

Keep your eyes on the sky.

Comment: I was really hoping this wasn't the best zoom scope. This is the one I have already. 6x times seems weak...